# ToastNotifier is not working because of win32api

Tags: python, winapi

**My Python code**

I am running python `.py` file from cmd.

This is what I am running:

```
import os, time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

path_to_watch = '//SERVER/shared_data/Technical/Label Sign Off Sheets/sign off project/To Sign'
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])

toaster = ToastNotifier()



while 1:
  time.sleep (10)
  after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
  removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
  if added: toaster.show_toast(str(added))
  if removed: print("Removed: ", ", ".join (removed))
  before = after
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\label\Desktop\Sign off project\test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from win10toast import ToastNotifier
  File "C:\Users\label\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from win32api import GetModuleHandle
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried re-installing `win32api` but warning shows up `Skipping win32api as it is not installed.`

**Python Version**

I am running on the latest Python version (as of 01/11/2019): 3.8.0